# Drupal 7 - bulk reference nodes using entity reference fields

Tags: drupal-7

I have 2 content types; publisher and campaign. When I create a campaign node, I then need to use entity reference to reference the publishers who will work on this campaign. I have added a reference entity field to my campaign content type however, I need to search and filter through my publishers to find the ones in the right category, then bulk add them using some kind of checkbox next to each. Anyone any idea how I can do this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [Entity Reference View Widget](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) module might do what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I thought I'd looked at everything but I don't think I have tried this. I'll try it out now. Cheers!

Comment: I cannot even get this working, can't get past here:    2) In the Field UI for the Entity Reference field select "View" as the widget
and on the next page select your View from the dropdown.  I only have this in my fields: The selected style or row format does not utilize fields.